# Is it ok to delete your downvoted post to get reputation back?

Tags: discussion, closing, voting

Recently, I've got a question with a score of -4, so I have deleted it and I got my reputation back. **Is this act considered to be ok?**

Comment: Note that in the case of deleting answers, the downvoters will also get their reputation back. (Downvoting questions is free)

Answer (score 5):

As long as there are no answers on it (i.e. you *can* self delete), yes.

There's even a badge for it so it's encouraged.

Comment: Reposting the question afterwards is seriously frowned upon though, since that is essentially shedding downvotes, and that is *not* allowed.

Comment: @Arperum - unless the new version is an improvement.  Such as the original question was unclear/showed no research, but a repost is of a greater quality.  I don't think that should be frowned upon (assuming the new question is of greater quality).

Comment: There is edit possibilities specifically for that reason. AN edited question gives a downvoter the option to change his vote again.

Comment: @Arperum Doing this more than once will trigger an automatic question ban, afaik.

Comment: I don't think it's 'encouraged' per se, the badge is more of a consolation prize then a reward for doing good: in an ideal situation you would edit the question and have it reopened/undownvoted/upvoted, instead of deleting. It's also worth mentioning that having a lot of deleted questions/answers can lead to a question/answer ban, so it's something you want to avoid doing if possible.